# error en el cambio de icono de fontawesome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap, css3

tengo varios botones en un foreach en php

```
 <table class="table-mp3 center-block" data-directorio-album="ideas" id="reproductor">

<?php foreach($canciones as $id => $cancion):?>
 <tr class="fila">
     <td>

<!-- <span class="icon-play">
  <i class="fa fa-play fa-1x icon start" data-directorio-album="ideas" data-id-cancion="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-archivo="<?php echo $cancion['archivo']; ?>"></i>

 </span> -->



  <button type="button" class="btn btn-ttc start" data-directorio-album="ideas" 
   data-id-cancion="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-archivo="<?php echo $cancion['archivo']; ?>">
   <i class="fa fa-play fa-1x icon"></i>
  </button>
```

este es el codigo para cambiar el icono

```
  $('#reproductor').find('[data-id-cancion="' + songId + '"]').removeClass( "fa-play" ).addClass( "fa-pause" );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el icono cambia pero mal como se ve en la imagen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error en la selección del elemento que deseas cambiar el icono.

Actualmente tienes:

```
$('#reproductor').find('[data-id-cancion="' + songId + '"]').removeClass( "fa-play" ).addClass( "fa-pause" );
```

Esto selecciona el botón que tenga `[data-id-cancion="' + songId + '"]` pero nunca selecciona el elemento que contiene la clase `fa-play`

Ahora si haces una nueva búsqueda dentro del elemento seleccionado quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#reproductor').find('[data-id-cancion="' + songId + '"]').find('i').removeClass( "fa-play" ).addClass( "fa-pause" );
```

Esto se puede resumir quedando:

```
$('#reproductor').find('[data-id-cancion="' + songId + '"] > i').removeClass( "fa-play" ).addClass( "fa-pause" );
```

Esta ultima buscará un elemento `i`  después de `[data-id-cancion="' + songId + '"]`